# MySQL - Getting the average per row

Tags: php, mysql, math

Let's say I have 3 MySQL table. A song db called `songs` that has a song's artist, album, etc. The main thing here is `lastfm_id` which is the song's UNIQUE id.

Then there's a `list` (with 10 spots, like top 10 songs). People can create lists by adding songs to their list and rank them 1 to 10. This db doesn't really needed to be touched for this.

Finally, we have `song_listed` which is the songs people picked to be put into a list. Here ti is:

[image]

As you can see, the `song_id` in `song_listed` is the same as `lastfm_id` in the table `songs`. Now since there is only one list in the database, there is 10 songs. If there 3 lists created, there would be 30 rows in `song_listed` each with their own rank of 1-10.

How would I get the average rank in the `song_listed` of each song in a list?

Imagine there's a page that shows a list via `list.php?id=11912` or something like that. 
You would then get the songs from `song_listed` where `list_id` was `11912`.

Here's what I got so far:

```
$listSongs = 0;
while ($listSongs <= 9) {

    // Don't worry, I did a query and $songID[x] works.
    $songID = $songID[$listSongs]; // ex: 12949331
    $getAvgRank = mysql_query("") or die(mysql_error());

    }
```

Comment: Could anyone throw the normal mysql_* comment?

Comment: if song A is in 2 lists on the 1st place, do you want it to be better than song B that is in 200 lists every time on 2nd place?

Comment: Avoid using the dated mysql_* functions. Using them for new code is highly
[discouraged](http://php.net/mysql_query).
More modern alternatives are available and better maintained.
Consider learning about
[prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)
instead and use either
[PDO or MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).
When used strictly they avoid the tedious and manual escaping part,
thus become heaps easier and as by-product safer to use.
See [a PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC) for starting.

Comment: @Truth, [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136610/179419)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT song_id, AVG(rank)
FROM song_listed
WHERE song_id in 
  (SELECT s1.song_id FROM song_listed s1 WHERE s1.list_id = <the id of your list_id>)
GROUP BY song_id
```

**EDIT**

if you want one request by song_id (which is not a great idea, but)

```
SELECT AVG(rank)
FROM song_listed
WHERE song_id = $songID[$realArray]
```

CAUTION : this is just the "logical" solution. Use parametrized queries (and read Ben' comment on mysql_* functions).

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?) group by song_id' at line 1` Hmmm

Comment: well, think you're able to change `?` by your parameter, no (for example 'gjX....') ?

Comment: Riiight. I got this `$getAvgRank = mysql_query("select song_id, AVG(rank) FROM song_listed WHERE song_id in (select s1.song_id from song_listed s1 where s1.list_id = $songID[$realArray]) group by song_id") or die(mysql_error());` and I output as `<?=$getAvgRank?>` and I get `resource id #13` or something like that.

Comment: @weka a) does `mysql_query` store the query or does it automatically execute the query? b) read the comments to your question about using `mysql_*` functions

Comment: @weka : something strange, you speak about list_id, then 11912, which looks like a song_id. So you want song_id, of list_id ?

Comment: `song_id` should be the ID of the song to use from `songs`. `List_id` is to sort of which list they are on.. whihc is naturally `$_GET['id']`

Comment: @weka well than use `$_GET['id']` as parameter. But with your actual code, look at my Edit then. (It's bad code, use parametrized queries).

Comment: Using your 'logical' solution, I get `Resource id #29` and such

Comment: Here is waht I am doing `$getAvgRank = mysql_query("SELECT AVG(rank) FROM song_listed WHERE song_id = $songID[$realArray]") or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: @weka try to print what's in `$songID[$realArray]` before passing it to your query. And /or show us your real code (more than what you show for instant in your question).

Comment: I finally got it using the logical solution. I will look more into prepped statements. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i don't thing average rank gives you the correct information - imagine 2 songs from a list - song A is present in 2 lists total, every time with rank 1,, song B in 200 lists, every time with rank 2 => song A will have average rank 1 and song B 2 even if it is much more popular

i suggest you to use a "popularity" metric instead (e.g. 10 points for rank 1 ... 1 point for rank 10):

```
select s.song_id, sum(11 - s.rank) popularity_points
from song_listed s
join song_listed l on s.song_id = l.song_id and l.list_id = :my_list_id
group by s.song_id
```